# Google Apps Script javascript reordering based on starting with word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to reorder worksheets in a Google Spreadsheet and I want to add some worksheets at the very beginning based on their full name or how they start. I can do it based on full name, but the "starts with" does not seem to work, e.g. the worksheets with the word Template in them don't go to the beginning of the list. Any ideas what might be wrong?

```
for (var key in sheets) {
    names[key] = sheets[key].getName();
}

names = names.sort();

// Resort with Changelog, then table list then Templates first
var first = "TABLELIST";

var second  = "Changelog";
names.sort(function(x,y){ return x == second ? -1 : y == second ? 1 : 0; });
// This actually does not change the order
var term = "Template";
names.sort(function(x,y){ return x.indexOf(term) ? -1 : y.indexOf(term) ? 1 : 0; });
```

Comment: `y.indexOf` is a function - did you mean to invoke that function with some argument?

Comment: I thought calling it with the argument term was the right way.

Comment: I realised I left a typo there, I copy+pasted again from my code now.

Comment: What do you know about the return values of `indexOf` and truthy/falsy type coercion? It should not be surprising based on your code that a string that starts with `term` is never sorted ahead of anything, only left unchanged or moved after. Additionally, it isn't clear if you're expecting the sheet tabs to reorder or not (i.e. is that comment for you & your maintainers, or for Stack Overflow, as a "this bit is wrong too" flag?)

Comment: I expect all worksheets that start with the word 'Template' to go to the beginning, but they don't, they go alphabetically at the end due to starting with 'T'.